# How to combine individual parts of address within a place dictionary for geocoding?

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding

At the moment, I have a place dictionary that contains values for all the different parts of a typical address, that I then pass through a geocoder. It looks like this:

```
[self.placeDictionary setValue:@"166 Bovet Rd" forKey:@"Street"];
[self.placeDictionary setValue:@"San Mateo"  forKey:@"City"];
[self.placeDictionary setValue:@"CA" forKey:@"State"];
[self.placeDictionary setValue:@"94402" forKey:@"ZIP"];

CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
[geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:self.placeDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    if([placemarks count]) {
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
        CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
        PFGeoPoint* userLocation = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
        NSLog(@"%f,%f", userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude); 
    } else {
        NSLog(@"location error");
        return;
    }
}];
```

Instead of having a separate dictionary entry for each individual part of the address, could I merge them into one string to pass through the geocoder? Something of this effect:

```
[self.placeDictionary setValue:@"166 Bovet Rd San Mateo CA 94402" forKey:@"Address"];
```

The reason I want to do this is I have a search bar in which a user is supposed to enter a location into for geocoding, and I can't divide it and extract each individual part of the address, so is there a way that I can pass the entire address like so, for geocoding?

edit: I've tried the following code and the terminal prints "location error":

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    [self.placeDictionary setValue:@"166 Bovet Rd San Mateo CA 94402" forKey:@"Address"]; 

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressDictionary:self.placeDictionary completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if([placemarks count]) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            PFGeoPoint* userLocation = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
            NSLog(@"%f,%f", userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude); 
        } else {
            NSLog(@"location error");
            return;
        }
    }];

    [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: this will also work..

Comment: It's giving me "location error" in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

After taking four values for keys Street, City, State & Zip you can create an additional key manually and store complete address in it otherwise you can store all these four values in four different strings and then save them collectively for any key in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I simply used the method `geocodeAddressString` instead.

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSString* address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"166 Bovet Road San Mateo CA 94402"];

    CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if([placemarks count]) {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
            PFGeoPoint* userLocation = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:coordinate.latitude longitude:coordinate.longitude];
            NSLog(@"%f,%f", userLocation.latitude, userLocation.longitude); 
        } else {
            NSLog(@"location error");
            return;
        }
    }];

    [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
}
```